# Access Git Repository using Eclipse and Netbeans Plugins with LDAP Users

Tags: eclipse, git, netbeans, ldap

I've configure a git server. I need to use ssh because I've defined permissions using users of my domain, using LDAP. Only users with permissions could read a project.
So, the links to access my repositories are like that: ssh://user@domain.com@hostname/var/git/repo.git

When I clone, commit or push a project using linux git commands or using tortoisegit on windows, there is no problem, everything works as expected.

However, I've tried to clone a project using plugins from Eclipse (EGit) and Netbeans (NBGit), with no success. Seems that they can't recognize the host. I've accessed using a user from the server (not from the domain) and it cloned the project perfectly. Seems that the plugins assume that the host is everything after the first @.

Do you know how I can solve this problem?
There are any other Git plugins for those IDEs?

Thanks for your answers.
Best Regards,
ukrania

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried putting a backslash before the first @ sign in Eclipse and Netbeans? This might escape the at-sign. Or, try replacing it with `%40`, the urlencoded version of @.

If neither of these solutions work, you might consider filing a bug report for these plugins. The only way the developers might fix it is if you let them know that this problem exists.

**edit** After further investigation of the [User Guide](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide), it looks like you should leave off the username from the URL. When you perform a Push To operation, or some operation that requires username and password, it will have fields for these. For example, in the following dialogs:

[image: EGet push dialog]

[image: EGet SSH login]

It is likely the same case for Netbeans.